# div with fixed height and z-index of -1000 in html structure

Tags: html, laravel, server-side-rendering

When I run my Laravel/blade website, it looks like Laravel adds an extra div at the bottom of my html structure.

[image]

It renders this on every page on my site so the height is different on each screen. I have a screen where i'm changing the height of the screen on the client side with a bootstrap accordion but the is fixed when the page was loaded. The problem is that the height of the screen isn't responsive to the height of the accordion. I can fix this problem by just setting the `height: auto;` in the inspector, but I cant find where this div is created in my code. Nor do I know what the function of this div is.

Comment: Hello, please give us the .blade.php file

Comment: Probably some sort of js plugin you use adding it

Comment: please check the plugins(js) you have used. make sure everything is authorized. 
looking like some malware activity

Comment: Thanks Pete, I deleted de JS scripts one by one and found out that SmoothScroll.js was responsible